# Double Array Error in Meshing with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, mesh

I have a mesh with a 0.1 radian slit.

```
mesh = makeSlitMesh(0.1,5)
```

its contents

```
        p: [2x188 double]
        t: [3x330 double]
    edges: [2x517 double]
      t2e: [3x330 double]
      e2t: [2x517 double]
```

My parameters for **get_solution_at_xy** function:

```
>> x = randn(100,1);
>> y = randn(100,1);
```

I run the function which code is below

> > get_solution_at_xy(@(x,y) sin(pi*x) .* sin(pi*y), mesh, x, y)

and get the error

```
Error using TriScatteredInterp
Sample values must be a double array.

Error in get_solution_at_xy (line 18)
    F=TriScatteredInterp(mesh.p(1,:)',mesh.p(2,:)',uh);
```

I have transposed the arrays **x** and **y**, but still get the same error.
The arrays are double.

**What can cause this error?**

**get_solution_at_xy function**

```
% Evaluates the FEM function "uh" defined on "mesh" at the points x,y
% 
% CALLING SYNTAX IS 
%
% function val = get_solution_at_xy(uh,mesh,x,y)
%
%   uh     = FEM function to be evaluated
%   mesh   = trimesh structure on which the FEM function is defined
%   x      = x coordinates of the evaluation points
%   y      = y coordinates of the evaluation points
%
%   val    = value of the FEM function evaluated at the points x,y
%

function val = get_solution_at_xy(uh,mesh,x,y)
    F=TriScatteredInterp(mesh.p(1,:)',mesh.p(2,:)',uh);
    val=F(x,y);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Sample values" in the error message from `TriScatteredInterp` refer to the variable `uh`, not `x` and `y`, which are double arrays as you pointed out.

However, with `uh` you are passing a **function handle** as the samples to `TriScatteredInterp`.  You need to either:

1. **[In `get_solution_at_xy.m`]** Evaluate `uh` at your mesh points.

   `uhvals = uh(mesh.p(1,:)',mesh.p(2,:)');`
   `F=TriScatteredInterp(mesh.p(1,:)',mesh.p(2,:)',uhvals);`
2. **[In caller]** Forget about the anonymous function and input the computed values instead of the formula.

   `uhvals = sin(pi*mesh.p(1,:)').*sin(pi*mesh.p(2,:)');`
   `get_solution_at_xy(uhvals, mesh, x, y)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is complaining is because the function TriScatteredInterp does not take a function but instead requires a double array in the third argument. This should fix your problem without the need to change the function code.

```
x = randn(100,1);
y = randn(100,1);
get_solution_at_xy(sin(pi*mesh.p(1,:)).*sin(pi*mesh.p(2,:)), mesh, x, y);
```

Comment: The use of `(x,y)` in the anonymous function is unfortunate as it makes the intent of the code less clear, with which your code is not quite consistent, _I believe_.  The function `get_solution_at_xy ` builds an interpolant `F` for given samples at specified locations.  Then it evaluates the interpolant at different locations (`val=F(x,y)`).  So it does not make much sense to use `x` and `y` to build the interpolant.  It should probably be the mesh, and here's where the anonymous function adds to the confusion.  I have clarified my solution to show the intent better.